# Square root of smooth function f(0)=0, f'(0)=0, f''(0)>0 is smooth?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand} \nc{\BR}{\mathbb R}$ Let $f: U \to \BR$ be a smooth function where $U$ is a neighborhood of $0\in \BR$ and $f$ is smooth. Furthermore, $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 0$, and $f''(0) > 0$. From this we can shrink $U$ to a set on which $f$ is nonnegative, so the square root is well-defined. I wish to show (conjecture) that $g(t) = \pm \sqrt{f(t)}$ is a smooth function. (where $g(t) = -\sqrt{f(t)}$ for $t<0$, $g(t) = \sqrt{f(t)}$ for $t \geq 0$)

Clearly the only issue is smoothness at 0. I read [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105438/square-root-of-a-positive-c-infty-function) which might be related, but in the counterexamples given $f''(0) = 0$, whereas I am assuming $f''(0) > 0$. I have shown directly (using limits) that $g'(0) = \frac{1}{2}f''(0)$ and that $g''(0) = g'''(0) = 0$. However, the form of $g^{(n)}(t)$ quickly grows very complicated to work with, so I am stuck with proving it in the general case.

Context: I wish to prove the Morse lemma in dimension 1. If I can show that $g$ is smooth, then its inverse $g^{-1}$ is a smooth change of coordinates near 0 (smooth by Inverse Function Theorem) such that $f(g^{-1}(t)) = t^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fixed $x$, since $f(0) = 0$, using the helper function $h_x(t) = f(t\cdot x)$, we can write

\begin{align}
f(x) &= h_x(1) - h_x(0)\\
&= \int_0^1 h_x'(t)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 f'(t\cdot x)\cdot x\,dt\\
&= x\cdot \underbrace{\int_0^1 f'(tx)\,dt}_{f_1(x)}.
\end{align}

Since $f$ is smooth, we can differentiate under the integral as often as we wish, hence $f_1$ is also smooth.

Now $f_1(0) = f'(0) = 0$, so we can make the same construction with $f_1$,

$$f_1(x) = x\cdot \underbrace{\int_0^1 f_1'(tx)\,dt}_{f_2(x)}.$$

By the same argument as above, $f_2$ is smooth. With

$$f_1'(x) = \int_0^1 s\cdot f''(sx)\,ds,$$

we can write

$$f_2(x) = \int_0^1 f_1'(tx)\,dt = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 s f''(stx)\,ds\,dt,$$

which shows

$$f_2(0) = \frac{1}{2} f''(0) > 0,$$

and by continuity $f_2(x) > 0$ on some neighborhood $V$ of $0$. On $V$, we have $g(x) = x\cdot \sqrt{f_2(x)}$, and as the square root of a strictly positive smooth function, $\sqrt{f_2(x)}$ is smooth. It follows that $g$ is smooth on $V$.

Comment: What was the motivation for constructing $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$?

Comment: I wanted to write $f$ in the form $f(x) = x^2\cdot h(x)$, to get a manageable form for $g$. The question is then whether $h$ is smooth. The trick of writing it as an integral is classical (I don't know who came up with that idea, unfortunately), and quite useful, since differentiability of integrals is relatively easy to handle. It's one of the tricks that are simple but very hard to find on one's own.